# CSS Semi-Absolutely Positioned Element when Scrolling

Tags: css

I have 3 columns that look something like this:

```
<div style="width:900px;margin:0 auto" id="container">
  <div style="width:100px; float:left">
    left
  </div>
  <div style="width:600px; float:left">
    main
  </div>
  <div style="width:200px; float:left" id="nav-col">
    <div id="navigation-list">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Not sure if this is possible, but I want the `#navigation-list` to stay on the screen whenever the window scrolls. It should stay about 100px down from the top of the document.body and also between left and right coordinates of the `#nav-col`

The main difficulty is that the `#container` will center itself dynamically when the window is resized.

Is there a way to do this in pure CSS?

Comment: Are you happy for the entirety of the `nav-col` to stay fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks its not possible with pure CSS..

You would need to use `position:fixed` on that element, but then it would not respect its container at all..

Comment: How could I modify this to keep the container in one place and still be web friendly?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The trick is to use `position: relative` on the enclosing container.</strike> Actually, it works sufficiently to just not specify `left` or `top` after `position: fixed`. That seems to do the trick. I also moved your styles into the CSS, and removed the 900px width ([for testing purposes](http://www.jsfiddle.net/PtpDf/1/)).

### CSS

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#container #left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}

#container #main {
    padding-right: 200px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}

#container #nav-col {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}

#container #navigation-list {
    position: fixed;
}​
```

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        left<br /> left<br /> left<br />
        left<br /> left<br /> left<br />
    </div>
    <div id="nav-col">
        <div id="navigation-list">
            nav<br /> nav<br /> nav<br />
            nav<br /> nav<br /> nav<br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br />
        main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br />
        main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br />
        main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br />
        main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br />
        main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br /> main<br />
    </div>
</div>​
```